# Scrapy script isn't passing settings to spider

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm trying to run a scrapy via a script but I think `get_project_settings()` isn't pointing to my `settings.py` regardless of being in the same directory as each other.

For some reason, it works sometimes when I choose "run code" but not with "run in terminal" in VSCODE.

script:

```py
import os 
import sys 
sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\Denze\\Projects\\testing\\amazonScraper\\amazonScraper")

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess 
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings 
from spiders.amazon_spider import AmazonSpider


class SpiderRunner():
    def __init__(self, spiderName):

        print("--REACTOR START INFO--")
        self.process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
        print("--REACTOR END--")
        self.spiderName = spiderName

    def scrape(self):
        self.process.crawl(self.spiderName)
        self.process.start()

SpiderRunner(AmazonSpider).scrape()
```

My pipeline isn't displayed in the console when the scrapy runs as being active like it should but my scraper runs. How do I fix this?

console pipeline line:

```
2021-08-03 16:35:52 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

`settings.py` location is defined by `settings.cfg`, e.g.

```
; settings.cfg

[settings]
default = spider_name.settings
```

From you description, obviously "run code" in VSCode didn't start from the project root and couldn't get `settings.cfg`.

Let's try this,

```py
import os 
import sys
PROJECT_ROOT = "C:\\Users\\Denze\\Projects\\testing\\amazonScraper"
os.chdir(PROJECT_ROOT)

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess 
...
```

BTW, you may not need to use `CrawlProcess` directly. `scrapy` provides `cmdline` to start spider from a script.

```py
import os 
PROJECT_ROOT = "C:\\Users\\Denze\\Projects\\testing\\amazonScraper"
os.chdir(PROJECT_ROOT)

from scrapy import cmdline    
cmdline.execute("scrapy crawl myspidername".split())
```

The only advantage of `CrawlerProcess` is that it supports starting multiple spiders at the same time.